# Zoom in Opengl ES

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I want to implement zoom in\out of my plaine object.

Now i try scaling :

```
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mFocalPoint.x, mFocalPoint.y, 0f);
    Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, mCurrentScaleFactor, mCurrentScaleFactor, 1f);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -mFocalPoint.x, -mFocalPoint.y, 0f);
```

In first zoom i have success result, but on the next zoom i have a problem - looks like a focal point calculated based on old matrix.

Here i calculated a **focal point**

```
    float glX = detector.getFocusX() * mScaleCoefX - mGLSceneWidth/2;
    float glY = mGLSceneHeight - detector.getFocusY() * mScaleCoefY - mGLSceneHeight/2;
    mFocalPoint = new PointF(glX, glY);
```

Also i save my model matrix after each zoom and restore before each draw.

**So i have a question**. Why my zoom doesn't work **`if i save matrix after each zoom`** and start scaling on new matrix?

Also - **maybe i should recalculate my mFocalPoint**?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use a Matrix, be sure to initialize it with the identity matrix before you use Translate, Scale or Rotate.  I don't see that in your code.  The calculated Matrix should then be multiplied to the projection matrix either before or in the Vertex shader.